# .sort() with number values stored as a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query a collection by a value called 'orderId'. orderId is an incrementing number, but it is stored as a string. Eg..

`[{orderId: '1'}, {orderId: '2'}, {orderId: '3'}]` etc.

This is my query:

```
Order.find().sort({"orderId": -1}).limit(1).exec(function (err, order) {...}
```

The problem is, this only returns up to a max orderId of '9' if I begin at 0 and increment by '1' each time. I'm assuming that this is because it is a string. I know this value should be stored as a number, but just for my own curiosity is it possible to find the highest value if it's stored as a string? Why does it stop at the value '9'?

Comment: "is this even possible" - what exactly is "this"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called ["lexicographic order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). In it, value "9" will be larger that value "123412341234716". If you want your values to sort like numbers, store them as numbers.

It doesn't stop at 9, though. "99" will be larger than "9".

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense. Thank you. I'm not sure why it stopped at 9, though. Anyway, I will just convert to a number. I was just curious if this was possible, but it seems like there would have to be a lot more formatting and processing and ultimately wouldn't be worth it. Cheers.